# Circular Image Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I want to show image in circle like profile picture into a [Navigation Drawer Layout](https://github.com/amarmesic/windows-phone-navigation-drawer) i am creating circular layout with this code.

```
 <Grid x:Name="ListFragment" >
     <StackPanel Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" >
         <StackPanel Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="OrangeRed" />
         <Ellipse Margin="0,-50,0,0" Height="100" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100">
             <Ellipse.Fill>
                 <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="Assets/admin.jpg"/>
             </Ellipse.Fill>
         </Ellipse>
     </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
```

Visual studio 2013 Designer showing perfect UI but when i run app on my phone app is crashing on initializing of Drawer Layout. what's going wrong? please help me.

Comment: Can you please provide the error given?

Comment: app is crashing without any error.

Comment: If you run the app connected to the debugger you will always get an exception thrown. Even if it is on the Unhandled exceptions handler.

Comment: And have you tried to put that code in the `MainFragment` grid instead of putting inside the `ListFragment`?

Comment: ya in MainFragment  also app is crashing

Comment: My guess is that the crash has nothing to do with the code you put here. If you don't add any information about the exception being thrown that causes the app to crash, there is little anyone can do to help you.

Comment: app is connected to the debugger but i am not getting any exception thrown

Comment: Nothing on the output console either?

Comment: My advice is that you download the demo project from here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb386b/implementing-navigation-drawer-for-windows-phone-8-1/ and then start by doing little changes to that until you find the reason for the crash.

Comment: ok let me try i will notify you tomorrow thank you.

Comment: I ran the code above on the 512 Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator and it worked fine. Using a png file. What are you running on?

Comment: solved it was problem with my image. I have replaced image with low resolution and now it works fine thank you.